# Refactor loop into a single line?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm taking a list of two arrays and concatenating them into one array and then returning it. Is it possible to simplify my .each do statement into one line? Additionally, what is a simpler way to write this?

```
def array_concat(array_1, array_2)
  array_2.each do |x|
    array_1.push x
  end
  return array_1
end
```

Ruby 2.1.1p76

Comment: BTW, you code doesn't create a new array. It appends the second array's items to the first array, thus changing `array_1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_1.concat(array_2)
```

................................

Comment: Wow....didn't think this whole thing would move into a single line. That did the trick, thank you WIZARD!

Comment: @theartofbeing Ruby is the Wizard.

Comment: It takes a Wizard to know a Wizard.

Comment: Not really. Dobby, for example, knows lots of wizards but he is not one himself. sawa has not shown himself to be a wizard by exercising any wizard powers, like casting spells.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it in various way in ruby :

Simplest way:

```
 [ 1, 2, 3 ] + [ 4, 5 ]
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Or**

Using [**concat**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-concat) : You can append the elements of other_array  to `self`

```
[ "a", "b" ].concat( ["c", "d"] ) #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Woow, Both works the same, then what is the **difference** between `+` and `concat`.

`+` would create a new array object while `concat` mutates the original object.

Let me show the example:

```
a = [1,2]
a.object_id # => 19388760 
a += [3]
a.object_id # => 18971360 


b = [1,2]
b.object_id # => 18937180 
b.concat [3]
b.object_id # => 18937180
```

**Note:** In above example `object_id` for `a` changed while for `b` did not change. ;) I hope this may helps you to understand.

Comment: For `a = [1,2,3]; b= [4,5,6]`, `[*a,*b]` is equivalent to `+`; `b.each { ||e| a<<b }; a` is equivalent to `concat`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Woooow, 1+ for this `[*a,*b]` its really cool. but when I try your this code `b.each{ |e| a<<b}`  I get `a=  [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]`

Comment: Whoops! That should have been `b.each{ |e| a<<e }; a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: Yeah now it works like charm.. Thanks for your optional solution. I will use it in future if required :)